# How can i delete border top radius bg transparency?

Tags: css, background, radius

How can i hide radius bg transparency? i don't want to see, when i scroll the my first landing page to up it will come to up with pages and showing up raidus corners background.

Thoose are ss's

[rad2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuXcN.png)

[rad1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fERwN.png)

and also you can view live : www.havadansantiye.com

look at the top of lef and right corner and scrool first page to up look now corners you will see bg.

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you made your question a little more specific. How is this implemented? Maybe put a sample on codepen and the like rather than a link to a site in development?

Comment: i added a my live web page  www.havadansantiye.com . you will see top left and right corner . when the page scroll up  look at the corners bacground i wanto to see corners white like bg white but when i scroll page to upside i am seeing my landing page bg pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have it fixed, overflow won't work because it is actually the content behind that is showing through. You could do a couple ways, but one might be to actually cover up the part of the header that is left uncovered by the border-radius. In order to do that though, you would need a separate element or a pseudo-element. You would make the header itself white to mask out, then use a pseudo :before to style the yellow area. Something like this should work:

```
.site-layout-bordered.header-horizontal #header {
   top: 30px;
   left: 30px;
   right: 30px;
   width: auto;
   background-color: white;
}
.site-layout-bordered.header-horizontal #header:before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   background: #fcc600;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Note, that the border-radius is moved to the pseudo-element so that the white covers the corner square (matching the surrounding area) and the pseudo creates the rounded effect–adding it to a pseudo-element is only to avoid adding additional HTML.

Comment: i dont know how to i add header before content can you edit my css file?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnPZ20Nn1DkGR54K2ez7bb9n1HR8SDhc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: ? waiting your answer

Comment: Sorry, I am at work so I got busy. In that file (it wouldn't let me edit it), remove line 1851 through 1858 and replace it with these two lines updated above to be more specific.

Comment: It seems to be working on your site link. Did you find a fix?

Comment: Yes when i clear my catch it works wow! Amazing!  Thank you my brothers!

Comment: Lol. Cache gets me every time. I have the Clear Cache plugin for chrome. I think I use it more than the refresh button :) - though if you have site caching on a server, that won't even help.

Answer (score 0):

use `overflow:hidden;`. replace `.div` to your class name

```
.div{
  overflow:hidden;
  border-radius:20px;
}
```

Comment: <pre> <code>.site-layout-bordered.header-horizontal #header {
    top: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    width: auto;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;

Comment: #header { top: 30px; left: 30px; right: 30px; width: auto; border-top-left-radius: 15px; border-top-right-radius: 15px; overflow:hidden; }

Comment: codepen is a website, where you can share your html, css, javascript code etc. an example https://codepen.io/rawan-al-faraj/pen/VggeWj

Comment: please help i researched i didnt find

Comment: please share html